# How to Quickly Find and Copy Paragraphs Containing Specific Texts in Word Document？（OR, leaving Paragraphs containing specific text in Word Document?）

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want write a code in Word VBA to quickly find and copy paragraphs containing specific texts in Word Document（OR, leaving Paragraphs containing specific text in Word Document）but have a line left incomplete. Here is the code that is very similar to my question but I want to cut/spike the paragraphs instead of deleting them, is there any one know how to write it? MANY Thanks in advance!

https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/quickly-find-delete-paragraphs-containing-specific-texts-word-document/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I changed a line to cut and add the selected paragraph to the spike (which I didn't know existed!)

The presence of the yes/no message box doesn't really let you review the paragraph however, but hopefully it'll work for you.

```
Sub SpikeParagraphsContainingSpecificTexts()
  Dim strFindTexts As String
  Dim strButtonValue As String
  Dim nSplitItem As Long
  Dim objDoc As Document

  strFindTexts = InputBox("Enter text strings to be found here, and use commas to separate them: ", "Text strings to be found")
  nSplitItem = UBound(Split(strFindTexts, ","))
  With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    ' Find the entered texts one by one.
    For nSplitItem = 0 To nSplitItem
      With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = Split(strFindTexts, ",")(nSplitItem)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute
      End With

      Do While .Find.Found = True
        ' Expand the selection to the entire paragraph.
        Selection.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
        strButtonValue = MsgBox("Click yes to cut/spike graf, no to do nothing", vbYesNo)
        If strButtonValue = vbYes Then
             NormalTemplate.AutoTextEntries.AppendToSpike Range:=Selection.Range

        End If
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.Execute
      Loop
    Next
  End With

  MsgBox ("Word has finished finding all entered text strings.")
  Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps! Thank you very much!